# Test with react-aria useButton gives me the famous "act" warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library, react-aria

I'm using react-aria and react testing-library.
In my Button component, i'm using react-aria's `useButton` and I use `onPress` prop to pass the function to call once click. In the unit test, I just try to click it in order to trigger a simple jest.fn() function, and all I do after that is check if function have been called.

```
const handleOnClick = jest.fn();
render(<Button onPress={handleOnClick}>test me</Button>);

userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));
expect(handleOnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

That is showing the following warning:

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to Button inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
```

If I wrap the click with act the warning is gone, but seems it's not a good practice to do that, because, in fact, testing library is doing an act internally in `userEvent` and  in other methods. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently facing this exact same problem. Have you been able to figure out a solution since?